# How to set custom layout attribute programatically

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app that uses a custom button library that uses custom attributes for setting the colours. How can I set these attributes programmatically to change them at runtime?

The library I am using is this one: https://github.com/SparkYuan/SubmitButton

```
<com.spark.submitbutton.SubmitButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="@color/mintBanner"
    app:sub_btn_background="@color/white"
    app:sub_btn_duration="2500"
    app:sub_btn_line_color="@color/mintBanner"
    app:sub_btn_ripple_color="@color/mintBanner"
    app:sub_btn_tick_color="@color/white" />
```

I want to set the attributes that begin with app:sub_btn.

Thanks.

Comment: just read the documentation of the library, it says explicitly "SubmitButton is a subclass of TextView, so almost all attributes of TextView can be used for SubmitButton". So just try youtTextViewid.setColor(Color.RED); for example

Comment: app:sub_button_duration for example is a custom attribute from this library, and is not a part of TextView so I cannot change it this way.

Comment: I looked at the SubmitButton component code, and it seems like it's missing the setters for the custom attributes. Usually you'd add public setter methods to custom components, to be able to change the attributes programmatically. You could potentially fork the repo and add them yourself... Doesn't look like the repo is being regularly maintained anyway